# How to change selected buttons background in a group of buttons in swift

Tags: ios, swift

I'm a beginner of swift. I have 4 buttons in my view. I want to change selected buttons background property to show user. Could you please help me thanks.

Comment: change the `backgroundColor` property, maybe... or it is an image you want to use, you friend is the `-setBackgroundImage:forState:` method, or I have no other ideas THB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If wanted them all to be the same color, you could connect them as an [IBOutlet Collection](http://nshipster.com/ibaction-iboutlet-iboutletcollection/) and then iterate through them using a `for in` loop and setting their `backgroundColor` properties.

```
for button in buttons {
      button.backgroundColor = UIColor.lightGreyColor()
}
```

Additionally if you wanted to set the color for states you can use these methods:

```
@IBAction func buttonClicked(sender: AnyObject) { //Touch Up Inside action
        button.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
 }

@IBAction func buttonReleased(sender: AnyObject) { //Touch Down action
        button.backgroundColor = UIColor.blueColor()

 }
```